# Adding a new file and calling functions from that file yields undefined function add_action()

Tags: php, wordpress, function, themes, undefined

I am adding a new file called subtypes.php to my theme /library/includes in order to allow for a dynamic dropdown list. This file uses functions from /library/functions/custom_functions.php.

The problem: whenever I call any function from custom_functions.php, I get fatal errors: Call to undefined function add_action(), other times I get undefined function get_option(). It seems to me that the new file doesn't load some default libraries or so....Any help willl be very much appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you post the rest of the add_action() error that states what file and line the error-causing code is?

Comment: Your problem is very curious since add_action() and get_action() are native WordPress functions that are defined in the WordPress Core.

Answer (score 0):

Put `include_once "../functions/custom_functions.php"` at the top of subtypes.php

Comment: I did it and that's why I get the fatal error for the add_action(). Here is how the  custom_functions.php look like
<?php>

add_action($blabla);

function A{}

function B{}

%>

I call function A() from subtypes and I get add_action() is undefined.

Thanks,
Youssef

Comment: Please edit your question and paste in the code from custom_functions.php that shows the `add_action()` function being defined.

Comment: Never mind. it's a hassle to clean the code and post it here! Thanks any way.

Comment: The problem is that we can't help you troubleshoot your code without seeing the code to begin with.

Comment: It's a long file that I need to sanitize, the structure was given above. I need to know how to tell a file to load some default hooks to understand the meaning of add_action() and get_option().....